# Roblox Players in Build mode

Tags: scripting, lua, roblox

Is it even possible to have two players in build mode? 
Look on the Roblox Developer's Journal article "[What did you sleigh?](http://blog.roblox.com/?p=3632)" It shows two "Players" on the players list.

Comment: It's a good thing you have that "roblox" tag, otherwise we'd have no clue what you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Roblox Studio
2. Go to any place and click Edit(Or press Ctrl + N for a completely blank place)
3. Click Tools
4. Click Test
5. Click Start Player
6. After the first player joined, repeat steps 3-5
7. There you go. 2 players in Edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually testmode. Open up ROBLOX Studio.  Go to `tools > Test > Start Server`

Then

- `tools > Test > Start Player`
- `tools > Test > Start Player`

Now you have 2 player's in 'build mode' though it's really test mode.  This is used to test player interaction for scripters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it. First open the level in Roblox Studio. Then Open the Tools Menu, Go to Test, then click Start Server. (You may get a security warning about connecting or something like that) When the new window opens, Go to Tools -> Test -> Start Player, but click it twice. Now you'll have two players on a testing server.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think that Roblox can sort of bend the rules for Robloxians like them. Like it is not like they are going to do something bad or hack into the system. My point is they needed to do that for a reason or else they couldnt chow you what those gear did

Answer (score 0):

You can can't. You can only do it in Group Build and you need BC for that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ROBLOX has deprecated build mode in favor of TeamCreate. For more information on this change, visit http://devforum.roblox.com/t/build-mode-discontinued/30222

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible, but you can edit in the same game by going into view, clicking Team Create, and inviting your friends. Your friends just need to press edit on your game. In view also press chat to talk inside studio.